# Write custom transformer in sklearn which returns .predict of estimator in .transform

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

We have a custom transformer

```
class EstimatorTransformer(base.BaseEstimator, base.TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, estimator):
        self.estimator = estimator

    def fit(self, X, y):
        self = self.estimator.fit(X,y)
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return self.estimator.predict(X)
```

And there is an assert statement

```
city_trans = EstimatorTransformer(city_est)
city_trans.fit(features,target)
assert ([r[0] for r in city_trans.transform(data[:5])]
        == city_est.predict(data[:5]))
```

where

> `city_est` is the estimator we can pass. I am using `city_est = city_est = Ridge(alpha = 1)`

but I get an error in `self = self.estimator.fit(X,y)`. What I might be doing wrong here. I know that `fit()` returns `self`. How should I make this assertion work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing wrong assignment in this line:

```
self = self.estimator.fit(X,y)
```

Here, self is the current class (EstimatorTransformer) and you are trying to assign it a different class.

You can just write:

```
def fit(self, X, y):
    self.estimator.fit(X,y)
    return self
```

and it will work.